# Minus operation for slices

Tags: rust, slice, pointer-arithmetic

How do I make to work the following code:

```
let arr: [u8; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
let x1: &[u8] = &arr[0..];
let x2: &[u8] = &arr[1..];
let d: isize = x2 - x1;
```

I have two slices into one vector and I want to know the difference between their start pointers (should be 1 in that example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of approaches is to convert pointers to slice contents to `isize` and do arithmetics on these values:

```
let arr: [u8; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
let x1: &[u8] = &arr[0..];
let x2: &[u8] = &arr[1..];
let d: isize = x2.as_ptr() as isize - x1.as_ptr() as isize;
println!("{}", d);
```

But I'm not sure how this would work if the address does not fit into `isize`.

Comment: *if the address does not fit into `isize`* => Do you mean, if the addresses fit in `usize` but not `isize`? In this case, you could convert to `usize` instead, though getting the difference without underflow would be slightly more complicated.